# Change button color depending on state

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a default green background. On `hover`, the background color is changed.

When the button is clicked, I want it to fall back to the green background.

How do I achieve this? I tried the following without success:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #4dd0e1
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #01579b
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #4dd0e1
}

.btn:visited {
  background-color: #4dd0e1
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="waves-effect btn"><i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>button</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```css
.btn{
  background-color: aqua
}
.btn:visited{
  background-color: yellow
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: skyblue
}
.btn:active{
  background-color: pink;
}
.btn:focus{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="waves-effect btn"><i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>button</a
```

You should follow **this order** when you write css code

1. `a:link`
2. `a:visited`
3. `a:hover`
4. `a:active`
5. `a:focus`

I don't know why, but it makes working your code.

You just change order of CSS Selectors (`:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
.btn:focus{ 
  background-color: #4dd0e1 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MaterializeCss colors helper clases 
[Materialize Colors](http://materializecss.com/color.html)

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn amber darken-4">button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one~

```
<style>
.btn:hover{background-color: #b44ce1}
.btn{background-color: #b44ce1}
</style

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Submit</a>
```

It works well for me~